# Losing context of this in a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, underscore.js

Here's an excerpt of my code:

```
'use strict'
var VocabApp = function (element, options) {
    this.options            =
    this.$element           = null
    ...
    this.controlsHolder     =
    this.test               =
    this.init(element, options)
}
VocabApp.prototype.init = function (element, options) {
        this.$element           = $(element)
        this.options            = this.getOptions(options)
        this.controlsHolder     = this.$element.find('nav.controls')
        this.test               = 'foo'
...
}
VocabApp.prototype.initUI = function () {
    console.log(this.controlsHolder)
    console.log(this.test)
    this.$element.find('.levels').on('click', ".level", _.bind(function (e)         {
            console.log(this.controlsHolder)
            console.log(this.test)
    }, this))
}
```

Why does `console.log` first print out the correct element, but then inside the callback prints out `undefined`? Shouldn't the `_.bind` preserve the context of this?

The strange part is that `this.test` correctly prints `foo` in both cases!

I've also tried using `$.proxy` and `var self = this` to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried debugging/outputting `this` in Web Inspector (or console) from your callback?

Comment: I don't see any `controlsHolder` declaration in `VocabApp`

Comment: Daniel, I just updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Note the init callback is changing the mentioned variable  to this.$element.find('nav.controls') and the constructor is also changing this variable.

I'd say that either the constructor or the init callback are running *after* initUI, changing the value of controlsHolder then.

Comment: But this.test works correctly! Yet it's also set in both places.